# Listview in firebase shows the same message twice in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, adapter

I have an app and it involves messaging, It sends and displays perfectly fine however it shows the same message twice in the listView which I really don't understand, I've seen other questions like this however they're all tailored to that specific question, here's my code:

Chat Activity (this is called whenever a message is sent):

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e("Chat details: ", String.valueOf(ds));
            chat_username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            chat_msg = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);

            Chat chat = new Chat(chat_username, chat_msg);
            chatList.add(chat);
            Log.e("Chat username: ", "" + chat_username);
            Log.e("Chat message: ", "" + chat_msg);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

My Chat List adapter:

```
public class chatListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Chat> {

    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;
    TextView usernameTV, messageTV;

    public chatListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Chat> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String username = getItem(position).getUsername();
        String message = getItem(position).getMessage();

        Chat chat = new Chat(username, message);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);


        usernameTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.username_chat);
        messageTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_chat);

        usernameTV.setText(username);
        messageTV.setText(message);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Chat model:

```
public class Chat {
    private String username, message;

    public Chat(String username, String message) {
        this.username = username;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

**Addon**:

My event Listener:

```
chatURLRoot.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                chatList.clear();
                append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

then whenever a message is sent it calls this method:

```
public String chat_msg, chat_username;

    private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e("Chat details: ", String.valueOf(ds));
            chat_username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            chat_msg = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);

            Chat chat = new Chat(chat_username, chat_msg);
            chatList.add(chat);
            Log.e("Chat username: ", "" + chat_username);
            Log.e("Chat message: ", "" + chat_msg);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: clear your arraylist before adding values.

Comment: Could you explain further? Sorry, I'm used to swift so I'm kinda new to this :)

Comment: @NathanEllis, please add `chatList.clear();` above line of for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) and check.

Comment: @NathanEllis, which `ValueEventListener` you use to fetch the value like `addValueEventListener` or `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` ?

Comment: @NiravBhavsar it's a addChildEventListener since it always has to be constantly listening for any more new messages?

Comment: @NathanEllis, ok so put `chatList.clear();` above calling of `addChildEventListener` and check

Comment: @NiravBhavsar that just clears the previous message that was in the listView everytime a new message is added, it also still shows the same message twice.

Comment: @NathanEllis, might i need to see your code then only its possible to check, can you please add your code of `addChildEventListener` in your question.

Comment: @NathanEllis, just to confirm please add full code of how you start and use of `addChildEventListener`

Comment: @NathanEllis, place `chatList.clear();` above `chatURLRoot.addChildEventListener` and also just to clarify are you maintaining the `ValueEventListener ` like `onPause` you are removing it like `reference.removeEventListener(chatURLRoot);` , if you not maintain then `addChildEventListener` will run multiple.

Comment: @NathanEllis, have you got any luck? if still you get multiple list problem then try to use `HashMap` instead of `ArrayList` as `HashMap` will override value.

Comment: @NiravBhavsar No, I tried that but since there's nothing in the arrayList when that code is first run it throws an error basically saying it cannot clear a null value? If that makes any sense? How would I go about a hashmap to do it? I don't want to change all the code, surely there's a way for it to not show the same value two times in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **clear** your list before adding new `DataSnapshot` like below

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        chatList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e("Chat details: ", String.valueOf(ds));
            chat_username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            chat_msg = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);

            Chat chat = new Chat(chat_username, chat_msg);
            chatList.add(chat);
            Log.e("Chat username: ", "" + chat_username);
            Log.e("Chat message: ", "" + chat_msg);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but it just adds it twice still but it also removes the previous messages

Comment: then you need to remove that position from list and then add new datasnapshot

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I'm new to android could you explain any further? Thanks so much